# Passing global variables as const reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants, global

The following code compiles and works. The value displayed of both a and n are 4.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 2;

void foo(int const&n)
{
    a = n*2;
    cout<<"a = "<<a<<"  n = "<<n<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(a);
}
OUTPUT: a = 4  n = 4
```

Why does the compiler not complain about n being a const reference? For example, the following code fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a = 2;

void foo(int const&a)
{
    a = a*2;
    cout<<"a = "<<a<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo(a);
}
OUTPUT:  In function 'void foo(const int&)':
10:7: error: assignment of read-only reference 'a'
```

How are the two cases different ?

Comment: The `const` keyword indicates that the object will not be mutated.  The first routine does not mutate the parameter.  The second routine mutates the parameter that the routine has promised not to mutate.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks, one thing I still don't understand is both 'n' and 'a' in the first example point to the same thing right ? As in both cases we are passing 'a' to the function. I was hoping the first case would also fail as at the end of the day we are mutating an object passed by const reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you're assigning to a global variable `a`. `n` changes because it's a reference to the mutable global variable. Changing `a` is allowed, but changing `n` directly is forbidden.

In the second case you're trying to re-assign to the `const` argument `a`. This is forbidden as `a` is `const`.

What you've done is [shadow global variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `a` with a local variable. In the second example, within `foo` the global variable named `a` does not exist, instead there's an argument that occupies that name.